# Python caught exception and continue

Tags: python

I've a little script in python that work in loop.
Every 30 seconds it get an url with `requests` to check if content of the page is changed.

But sometime I get script error (about 1 time a day):

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x.......>: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution))
```

What it the best  way to intercept exception and, if occurs, wait another 30 seconds and continue the script instead stop it?
The exception to caught is `ConnectionError` or `NewConnectionError` ?

Comment: You mean retry the connection after 30sec? Do you only want to retry once, or else how many times?

Answer (score 1):

Put a try/except around your code, like this:

```
try:

# your code here

except ConnectionError:
    pass
except NewConnectionError:
    pass
```

Comment: Hi thanks. So, are ConnectionError and NewConnectionError correct in my example? Or there are other exception? HTTPSConnectionPool is it? VerifiedHTTPSConnection is it?

Comment: There are other Exceptions. You can add them as you encounter them, or add the ones from the docs that you think are appropriate :) https://2.python-requests.org/en/v3.0.0/_modules/requests/exceptions/